# Can Interface be used as key in Coherence Cache?

Tags: caching, oracle-coherence

I have 2 different types of keys:

```
interface Key extends Serializable {
   String getName();
}

class KeyA implements Key {
    private String name;
    private int fieldA;
}

class KeyB implements Key {
    private String name;
    private int fieldB;
}
```

Can I use `Key` interface as a key in **Coherence** partitioned cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you must ensure that all possible implementations of `Key` meet following preconditions (from [Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18686_01/coh.37/e18692/strings.htm#BEIFDJJI)):

> Cache keys must also provide an implementation of the `hashCode()` and
>   `equals()` methods, and those methods must return consistent results
>   across cluster nodes. This implies that the implementation of
>   `hashCode()` and  `equals()` must be based solely on the object's
>   serializable state (that is, the object's nontransient fields).
>
> ...
>
> Some cache implementations (specifically the **partitioned cache**) use
>   the serialized form of the key objects for equality testing, which
>   means that **keys for which the `equals()` method returns true must
>   serialize identically**.

There is a good [article](http://blackbeanbag.net/wp/2010/06/06/coherence-key-howto/) by Patrick Peralta that explains this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

An instances of a class which is implementing that interface could be used as a key here.